# ref argument in C#

Tags: c#, .net

First of all I am new to C# programming.

I read the parameter of

```
ImageObj.getBounds(ref GraphicsUnit unit);
```

When I tried this,

```
ImageObj.getBounds(ref GraphicsUnit.Pixel);
```

I still got the error. But this seemed to work perfectly fine.

```
GraphicsUnit u = GraphicsUnit.Pixel;
ImageObj.getBounds(ref u);
```

What is the difference between the two and how is the first wrong? Thank You.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

`GraphicsUnit.Pixel` is a property, you can not pass properties with `ref`/`out` parameters in C#. It's because `ref`/`out` is like pointer to pointer in other languages but property is not a variable - it's a 2 methods: getter and setter, so, you can't pass a pointer to pointer to value because you haven't value itself.

Added:
Ok, `GraphicsUnit.Pixel` actually is an `enum` member - you also can't pass it with `ref`/`out` parameters because it's a constant.

Comment: Lord, I was having a brain fart... Thank you for a concise explanation!

Answer (score 5):

`GraphicsUnit.Pixel` is a constant, as it's a member of an enumeration.  As such, it can't be passed in to a function that expects a reference to a GraphicsUnit - getBounds may try to modify the value and this obvsiouly can't work.

Comment: Oh and this is not possible to do in Java I guess ? Isn't it always by value?

Comment: No - Java doesn't allow passing simple types by reference.

Answer (score 4):

The `ref` keyword must refer to a variable. A property isn't a variable. It's a special kind of member that wraps a backing field (which *is* a variable you can use with `ref`). Additionally, `ref` marks a variable to be modified by the method; that means if it's a reference to something, **the reference is changed, not the object being referenced**.

The second snippet works because you're assigning the contents of `GraphicsUnit.Pixel` to a local variable to be manipulated by the method.